# 3 validation errors- unsure of how to correct

Tags: html, validation

1. Line 10, Column 43: Bad value FRSH Studio for attribute href on element link: Whitespace in path component. Use %20 in place of spaces. `<link rel="pingback" href="FRSH Studio" />`
   --- It is my understanding that this is pulled from my settings in Wordpress. When I change the setting to include the %, I'm given an error stating that "Path component contains a percent sign that is not followed by two hexadecimal digits." How do I fix this?
2. Line 146, Column 7: End tag for body seen, but there were unclosed elements. `</body>`
   --- I believe this is referring to `<div id="container">`...
3. Line 54, Column 20: Unclosed element div. `<div id="container">`
   --- When I close the container using `</div><!-- end container -->` in the footer, I'm told that it is a stray tag. Where should `</div><!-- end container -->` be?

Not sure why this was sent away from Wordpress Stackexchange. The site validates as HTML. It is only when validating the site, which is Wordpress, using the URI via w3c's validator that these errors arise.

Comment: HTML validation errors are not a WordPress issue. Migrating instead to Stack Overflow.

Comment: @EAMann Not sure why this was sent away from Wordpress Stackexchange. The site validates as HTML. It is only when validating the site, which is Wordpress, using the URI via w3c's validator that these errors arise.

Comment: As written, your question has nothing to do with WordPress.  You outline some HTML validation errors and ask for help.  HTML validation is not a WP issue, which is why your question was migrated.

Comment: @user1255049 did any of these answers help? If so please vote up and choose a correct answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Put the full code inside the HTML Tidy and make it valid. Use this: http://infohound.net/tidy/

**HTML Tidy** is a tool for checking and cleaning up HTML source files. It is especially useful for finding and correcting errors in deeply nested HTML, or for making grotesque code legible once more.

This online version enables you use it without installing the client tool on your PC.

Answer (score 0):

The "stray tag" error may be due to the fact that the page is being parsed as XHTML, where every opening tag (e.g. `<!-- end container -->`) requires a closing tag.

The best HTML validator is here:

http://validator.w3.org/

That will offer an option to clean up with HTML Tidy as others have mentioned.

Comment: I'm aware of, and use, validator.w3.org. In fact, the site validates fine as an HTML site. It was only when switching from HTML to utilizing Wordpress' hooks that the validation errors arose.

Comment: Then the problem must be that you are validating it as an HTML site, you should validate it as XHTML so it will detect that all tags must be properly closed.

Answer (score 0):

**1) The href has to be a valid link.**

```
<link rel="pingback" href="http://frshstudio.com" />
```

**2/3) Perhaps you have closed it in the wrong place?**

Can you please post code?

Answer (score 0):

Your site appears to be generating bad HTML pages.

1) The value for "href" should be a URL.

2) If you have a "div" start tag, then there needs to be a "div" end tag as well. This may be missing.

3) Would need to see the entire source to be helpful.

As someone suggested, you can use http://validator.w3.org/. Another validator (for Windows so it's offline and it does a lot more) is CSE HTML Validator at http://www.htmlvalidator.com/